# How to buffer and group elements in Reactor Flux in Java

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor

Given an infinite flux of objects, where each object has an ID, how can I use flux to create a buffered list of updates grouped by ID property (keeping the last emitted value)?
Thanks

Example

```
    Obj(ID=A, V=1)
    Obj(ID=A, V=2)
    Obj(ID=B, V=3) 
    --- buffer -> I want to subscribe with a list of [Obj(ID=A, V=2), Obj(ID=B, V=3)]
    Obj(ID=A, V=1)
    Obj(ID=B, V=4)
    Obj(ID=B, V=6)
    Obj(ID=A, V=2)
    --- buffer -> I want to subscribe with a list of [Obj(ID=B, V=6), Obj(ID=A, V=2)]
    Obj(ID=B, V=1)
    --- buffer -> I want to subscribe with a list of [Obj(ID=B, V=1)]
```

Something like the following would be perfect but it seems to wait the end of the flux in my tests instead of buffering.

```
flux
    .buffer(Duration.ofMillis(2000))
    .groupBy(Obj::getId)
    .flatMap(GroupedFlux::getLast)
    .collectToList()
    .subscribe(this::printList);
```

It works with buffer and custom logic for grouping

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        flux.buffer(Duration.ofMillis(2000)).subscribe(this::groupList);
    }

    private void groupList(List<T> ts) {
        Collection<T> values = ts.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(T::getId, Function.identity(), (k, v) -> v))
                .values();
        System.out.println(values);
    }
```

Comment: How about this instead `.groupBy(Obj::getId).flatMap(group -> group.window(Duration.ofMillis(2000).flatMap(Flux::last)).collectToList()`?

Comment: Not working, it waits the end of the flux to print, I think this is collect* behavior. Without collect it's better, I'm working on that. Thanks

Comment: Well, that's your call to use a `collectToList()`. Not sure why you blame us for not working. It is really expected: see its JavaDocs: `Collect all elements emitted by this {@link Flux} into a {@link List} that is emitted by the resulting {@link Mono} when this sequence completes`

Comment: Yeah exactly, sorry I mean not working for my use case, I'm trying to create a list for each iteration, without wait for the sequence to complete.

Comment: Then `buffer()` instead of `collectToList()`: `* Collect incoming values into multiple {@link List} buffers that will be emitted by the returned {@link Flux} every {@code bufferingTimespan}.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to achieve it with the reactive grouping

```
flux.window(Duration.ofMillis(2000))
    .flatMap(window -> window.groupBy(Entry::getId)
        .flatMap(GroupedFlux::last)
        .collectList()
    )
    .subscribe(this::printList);
```

Answer (score 0):

`buffer` will emit `List<T>`, therefore you could just use non-reactive java to group by. For example, java streams like in your example. Assuming your process function is reactive, you could continue the flow

```
flux
    .buffer(Duration.ofMillis(2000))
    .map(list -> list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getId, Function.identity(), (k, v) -> v)))
    .flatMapIterable(Map::values)
    .flatMap(obj -> process(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a somewhat similar use case. Have simulation data on AWS S3. The data is stored as JSON records in chunks of 512. Need to download a variable number of these chunks and transform them into a single JSON array. The transformer signals that it needs no more records by returning the number of transformed records - which would be zero when there is no need of further records. Below are two snippets of code. The first uses *Flux.window* while the latter uses *Flux.buffer*. The latter executes at about one tenth the speed of the former but downloads more data than is absolutely necessary.

*Flux.window* code

```
    Flux<Flux<S3Object>> s3Objects = Flux.fromIterable(filteredList).window(windowSize);
    Integer cumulativeSize = s3Objects.concatMap(innerS3Objects -> {
        Flux <File> downloadedFiles = innerS3Objects.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).concatMap(s3Object -> downloadS3Object(BUCKET_NAME, s3Object.key()));
        return downloadedFiles.publishOn(Schedulers.single()).concatMap(downloadedFile -> {
            return transformMockarooData(downloadedFile, generator, targetHourCount);
        }).takeUntil(transformedRecordCount -> (transformedRecordCount == 0)).reduce((i,j) -> i + j);               
    }).takeUntil(transformedRecordCount -> (transformedRecordCount == 0)).reduce((i,j) -> i + j).block();
```

*Flux.buffer* code

```
    Flux<List<S3Object>> s3Objects = Flux.fromIterable(filteredList).buffer(windowSize);
    Integer cumulativeSize = s3Objects.concatMap(innerS3Objects -> {
        List <Mono<File>> toDownloadFiles = innerS3Objects.stream().map(s3Object -> downloadS3Object(BUCKET_NAME, s3Object.key())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Flux <File> downloadedFiles = Flux.merge(toDownloadFiles);
        return downloadedFiles.publishOn(Schedulers.single()).concatMap(downloadedFile -> {
            return transformMockarooData(downloadedFile, generator, targetHourCount);
        }).takeUntil(transformedRecordCount -> (transformedRecordCount == 0)).reduce((i,j) -> i + j);               
    }).takeUntil(transformedRecordCount -> (transformedRecordCount == 0)).reduce((i,j) -> i + j).block();
```